# I have a route component, why are my props not automatically updating when I set them in the route definition?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-props

I have my index book that list all the registered books and when I click to edit a specif book it does get the specif book's id in the route but my props element does not get it, what gives an error!
How can I fix it?

Below I have the code on my index page:

`<router-link :to="{ name: 'update_book', params: {id: book.id} }">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="pen-square" />
                </router-link>`

In my update page I have:

```
<script>
 props: ['id'],
 data() {
  return {
   books: [],
  };
 },
 methods: {
  getBook(id) {
   axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books/${id}`) // Gets an specif book
    .then((response) => { this.books = response.data; });
 },
 created() {
  this.getBook(this.id);
 },
 watch: {
  $route() {
   this.getBook(this.id);
 },
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you define the route? My understanding is that the param will only be set automatically if it's a "route component". See the example [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components).

Comment: {
    path: '/update_book/:id',
    name: 'update_book',
    component: UpdateBook,
    props: true,
  },

Comment: why should id be there? params does not pass anything to props

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router do not pass `id` to props.In your case you can find `id` in `this.$route.params`

Even if you use something like `/book/:id` in router itself, that `id` param will live in `this.$route.params.id`.

So you need something like :

```
 created() {
  this.getBook(this.$router.params.id);
 },
```

And btw, in watcher too.

[image]

Comment: I get this error "TypeError: this.$router.params is undefined"

Comment: my bad.`this.$route` not routeR

Comment: no problem bro, mb it is better to change question for something  'how to get params from route in vue-router' ?

Comment: Yeah, I assume this works. I think the original question could be better phrased as, "I have a [route component](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components), why are my props not automatically updating when I set them in the route definition?" The answer to that remains to be seen.

Comment: Agree with Mr. from  the City. Can i  edit  it to get some cheap karma?)

Comment: Thanks David, that sounds better!!

Comment: For sure Bonusrk!!LOL